# Why is my entry in the HashTable not found?

Tags: ocaml

I have the following code:

```
let to_permutation pairs max_el =
  let tbl = Hashtbl.create 100 in
  let rec aux i collector = 
    if i > max_el then collector
    else 
      match Hashtbl.find_opt tbl i with
        None ->   
          ignore (Printf.printf "NOT found \n");
          Hashtbl.add tbl i 1;
          aux (i + 1) (List.append (List.hd collector) [List.assoc i pairs] :: List.tl collector)           
      | Some _ ->
          ignore (Printf.printf "Found\n");
          aux (i + 1) (List.append [[]] collector)  
  in
  aux 1 [[]];;
```

What it's supposed to do: when I give the function a list of pairs, then I want it to generate me cycles of mapped integers ( based on the pairs. )

Example: `to_permutation [(1, 6); (2, 3); (3, 5); (4, 1); (5, 2); (6, 4)] 6;;` should return something like `[[1; 6; 4]; [2; 3; 5]];`.

However I'm not even close to this, because the lookup to check if I already visited an element (and thus detected a cycle) fails. The output of the program:

```
to_permutation [(1, 6); (2, 3); (3, 5); (4, 1); (5, 2); (6, 4)] 6;;
NOT found 
NOT found 
NOT found 
NOT found 
NOT found 
NOT found 
- : int list list = [[6; 3; 5; 1; 2; 4]]
```

Although I insert into the hash table, it never finds an element. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the call to `aux i`, you are maintaining the invariant that the table `tbl` only contains keys that are strictly inferior to `i`. Thus `find_opt tbl i` always return `None`, and you add an `i` key to `tbl` before calling `aux (i+1)` preserving the invariant stated earlier.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, I'm quite new to OCaml. What does "strictly inferior" mean in this context? And, a fix would be to pass the hash table along when recursively calling `aux` maybe?

Comment: If you have a key `k` in `tbl`, then `k < i`

Comment: OK, I think I can't see yet how this invariant that the keys are all lower than 1 is defined in the above code. Is there a way to fix it and allow inserts for any keys?

Comment: You are not inserting "any" keys. You are inserting keys in increasing order and always looking for a key that is greater than any key you ever have inserted. It is unclear what the `i` argument is supposed to be.

Comment: I got it now what you mean and that indeed helped me to track down the bug in the logic. Thanks! I was under the wrong impression that I'm doing sth wrong when inserting to the hashtable, that caused my confusion.